# How to make FileFilter in Java?

Tags: java, filefilter

How to make a filter for .txt files?

I wrote something like this but it has an error:

```
 private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        int retval = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        
        String yourpath = "E:\\Programy Java\\Projekt_SR1\\src\\project_sr1";
        File directory = new File(yourpath);
        String[] myFiles;
        FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName) {
            return fileName.endsWith(".txt");
        }
        };
        myFiles = directory.list(filter);

        
        if(retval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            File myFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        }
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) you will find some working examples. [This](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JFileChoosersetFileFilterFileFilterfilter.htm) is also a good example of FileFilter used in JFileChooser.

The basics are, you need to override [FileFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html) class and write your custom code in its accpet method. The accept method in above example is doing filtration based on file types:

```
public boolean accept(File file) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      String path = file.getAbsolutePath().toLowerCase();
      for (int i = 0, n = extensions.length; i < n; i++) {
        String extension = extensions[i];
        if ((path.endsWith(extension) && (path.charAt(path.length() 
                  - extension.length() - 1)) == '.')) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or more simpler to use is [FileNameFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) which has accept method with filename as argument, so you don't need to get it manually.

Answer (score 50):

Try something like this...

```
String yourPath = "insert here your path..";
File directory = new File(yourPath);
String[] myFiles = directory.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName) {
        return fileName.endsWith(".txt");
    }
});
```

Comment: in line return !fileName.endWith(".txt"); i'm getting error endWith - cannot find symbol

Comment: ok now no error but when i run aplication i can select all kind of files not only txt :( some ideas?

Comment: The problem is the ! character in `return !fileName.endsWith(".txt");`. Remove the ! and you will only accept txt files.

Comment: i did that and when i run aplication and click my menuitem it shows JFileChooser but i can select all kinds of files in question i edit my code :)

Answer (score 11):

From JDK8 on words it is as simple as

```
final String extension = ".java";
final File currentDir = new File(YOUR_DIRECTORY_PATH);
File[] files = currentDir.listFiles((File pathname) -> pathname.getName().endsWith(extension));
```

Answer (score 7):

Since Java7 you can simply use `FileNameExtensionFilter(String description, String... extensions)`

A simple JFileChooser analog to the example would be:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text files", "txt"));
```

I know the question was answered long ago, but this is actually the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a little utility class that I created:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Convenience utility to create a FilenameFilter, based on a list of extensions
 */
public class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    private Set<String> exts = new HashSet<String>();

    /**
     * @param extensions
     *            a list of allowed extensions, without the dot, e.g.
     *            <code>"xml","html","rss"</code>
     */
    public FileExtensionFilter(String... extensions) {
        for (String ext : extensions) {
            exts.add("." + ext.toLowerCase().trim());
        }
    }

    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        final Iterator<String> extList = exts.iterator();
        while (extList.hasNext()) {
            if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(extList.next())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
       String[] files = new File("myfile").list(new FileExtensionFilter("pdf", "zip"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple example:

```
public static void listFilesInDirectory(String pathString) {
  // A local class (a class defined inside a block, here a method).
  class MyFilter implements FileFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
      return !file.isHidden() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt");
    }
  }

  File directory = new File(pathString);
  File[] files = directory.listFiles(new MyFilter());

  for (File fileLoop : files) {
    System.out.println(fileLoop.getName());
  }
}

// Call it
listFilesInDirectory("C:\\Users\\John\\Documents\\zTemp");

// Output
Cool.txt
RedditKinsey.txt
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going wrong here:

```
int retval = chooser.showOpenDialog(null); 
public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName) {`
return fileName.endsWith(".txt");`
}
```

You first show the file chooser dialog and then apply the filter! This wont work. First apply the filter and then show the dialog:

```
public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName) {
        return fileName.endsWith(".txt");
}
int retval = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File f = null;
File[] paths;

try {

    f = new File(dir);

    // filefilter
    FilenameFilter fileNameFilter = new FilenameFilter() {

        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {

            if (name.lastIndexOf('.') > 0) {

                int lastIndex = name.lastIndexOf('.');
                String str = name.substring(lastIndex);

                if (str.equals("." + selectlogtype)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    paths = f.listFiles(fileNameFilter);

    for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        try {

            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("C:/Users/maya02/workspace/ftp_log/filefilterlogtxt");
            PrintWriter bWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);

            for (File writerpath1 : paths) {
                bWriter.println(writerpath1);
            }

            bWriter.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) { System.out.println("HATA!!"); }
    }
    System.out.println("path dosyaya aktarıldı!.");
} 
catch (Exception e) { }
```

Comment: What value does your answer add to a 5 years old question? What's the difference between your answer and the other answers?

Answer (score 0):

... What about using Apache's FileFilters from:
`org.apache.commons.io`?

just like:

```
 import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.FileFileFilter;
 import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.WildcardFileFilter;

 ...

 File dir = new File(".");

 String[] filters = { "*.txt"};
 IOFileFilter wildCardFilter = new WildcardFileFilter(filters, IOCase.INSENSITIVE);

 String[] files = dir.list( wildCardFilter );
 for ( int i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
     System.out.println(files[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

FileFilter filtro=new ExtensionFileFilter("Excel", ".csv");

Comment: Please explain how this snippet of code answers the question.

Comment: Explain more please