# find specific file type from folder and its sub folder

Tags: java, file, io, file-search

I am writing a method to get specific file type such as pdf or txt from folders and subfolders but I am lacking to solve this problem. here is my code

```
  // .............list file
    File directory = new File(directoryName);

    // get all the files from a directory
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

    for (File file : fList) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listf(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
```

My current method list all files but I need specific files

Comment: Google for FileFilter or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603966/how-to-make-filefilter-in-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(file.getName().endsWith(".pdf")) {
    //it is a .pdf file!
}
```

/*********/

Answer (score 10):

For a filtered list without needing recursion through sub directories you can just do:

```
directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith(".pdf");
    }});
```

For efficiency you could create the FilenameFilter ahead of time rather than for each call.

In this case because you want to scan sub folders too there is no point filtering the files as you still need to check for sub folders. In fact you were very nearly there:

```
File directory = new File(directoryName);

// get all the files from a directory
File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

for (File file : fList) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
       if (file.getName().endsWith(".pdf")) {
           System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
       }
    } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
        listf(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your logic but it works only with root directory not with sub folders ...

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I missed the requirement for recursion. Yes you are right, this will not list sub folders (unless they happen to end with .pdf). In this case since you need to scan all the files anyway going with the other suggestions of just checking the filename is probably your simplest suggestion. - I'll edit my answer.

Comment: What is "listf(file.getAbsolutePath())"?  I cannot seem to resolve listf

Comment: @Lismore create a method called listf - put this as the contents of the method.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the FilenameFilter interface in you function
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-find-files-with-certain-extension-only/ - for a code that has extention filter

Answer (score 1):

Use [File.listFiles(FileFilter)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29).

Example:

```
File[] fList = directory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.getName().endSwith(".pdf");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache fileUtils class

```
String[] exte= {"xml","properties"};
Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(new File("d:\\workspace"), exte, true);

for(File file: files){
     System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String[],%20boolean)) or [NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/).
[NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/) allows Stream with Depth-First search, for example you can print all files with a specified extension in one line of code:

```
Path path = Path.get("/folder");
try{
    Files.walk(path).filter(n -> n.toString().endsWith(".extension")).forEach(System.out::println)
}catch(IOException e){
    //Manage exception
}
```